# Adobe Brackets; How to use the replace regexp function?

Tags: regex, find-and-replace

I searched the Brackets user guide [@github](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets) and couldn't find how can I use the the search and replace function inside of the program. A simple example is to find `foo` and replace it with `bar` in a string `barfoobar`. It says; (use /re/ syntax for regexp search)
I'm new to Brackets and regular expressions too, but normally I should have two fields one for the search and the other one for replace. In bracket there's only one field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops! I just found that I have to push enter and Adobe Brackets will ask for the replace string! what a complex UI :/

Comment: Yeah, we know that a better UI here is needed. I'm glad you were able to work it out, though.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I see that you are among the Adobe Brackets team :)

Comment: Note that the UI is much different in newer versions -- see answer & screenshot below.

Answer (score 2):

In more recent versions of Brackets, the Replace command gives you a much better experience:

[image: Brackets Replace UI]

[Read this blog post](http://blog.brackets.io/2013/12/20/brackets-sprint-35-build/) for more details.